# How to C# pass exception message to JQuery Ajax event using web methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, exception, webmethod

I am using JQuery to make an ajax call to a C# WebMethod. On our dev boxes, when an error occures in the C# code, the error message is passed to the error event of the $.ajax function. However, on our production machines, I just get a generic "An error has occured" message back. But as I throw my own exception in my C# code with their own messages that are relevant to the user, I need to get those and not the generic ones. Does anybody know how to pass an error message in a clean way here?

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/" + _spPageContextInfo.layoutsUrl + "/FinanceTallyWS.asmx/GetBillableContracts",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ reviewerId: id }),
    error: (e) => {
        dfd.reject(JSON.parse(e.responseText).Message);
    },  
    success: (data) => {
        dfd.resolve(JSON.parse(data.d)); //How to pass exception message to here?
    }
});

[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetBillableContracts(int reviewerId)
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()))
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var contracts = FinanceTally.GetBillableReviewerContracts(reviewerId, site); //Here I throw an exception with custom message
        return serializer.Serialize(contracts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the Web.config in production is set to not show exception information.  This is usually done by default because this is usually a very good idea.  Attackers can sometimes use exception information to learn more about the inner workings of the system.  If you're *very confident* that all possible error conditions generate "friendly" exceptions, then you can change this in the Web.config.

Comment: Is there some other way I can pass my exception to the front end? I just need the custom error message of my custom exception, all other exceptions can return with generic errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can add try catch in your web method like

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetBillableContracts(int reviewerId)
{
  JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  try{
      using (SPSite site = new SPSite(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()))
      {

        var contracts = FinanceTally.GetBillableReviewerContracts(reviewerId, site); //Here I throw an exception with custom message
        return serializer.Serialize(contracts);
    }
  }catch(Exception ex){
    // set status to 500 here and return you message
    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 500;
    return serializer.Serialize(new { Message = ex.Message});
 }
}
```

Comment: this works on our dev box, but I still have to try it on production.

Comment: Try this surely this is what you want i think

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are sent to the error function and look something like this

```
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                msg = 'Time out error.';
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
            } else {
                msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
            }
            $('#TextControlToPostTheErrorTo').html(msg);
```